# How to add UISearchBar to UIView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to add a `UISearchBar` to an `UIView` instead of an `UIViewController`, the problem is that the init method of `UISearchDisplayController` needs an `UIViewController` as `contentsController:`.
I can see the `UISearchBar` correctly displayed in the view but if I click in it, the bar disappears. Here is my code I'm currently using:

```
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    // this was my approach, but this DOES NOT work
    UIViewController *results = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    results.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self insertSubview:results.view aboveSubview:self.menuList];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:results];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

Before:

[image]

After clicking into search bar:

[image]

Comment: could you add a screen shot pls

Comment: try to add this `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` in `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: The problem is, that the search bar is inside a custom UIView not in an UIViewController. I'm pretty sure this causes the problem, but unfortunately I have no other possibility because my UIView is a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

In swift,

I use `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to solve this problem.

This problem seems like after the search bar is clicked, it will automatically hide the bar. And it will be fine after you click outside the view.

I add this line:

`self.searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;`

Hope it works